# What is the expected output if we use \r in Python [Pycharm]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, carriage-return

I wrote `print("Hell\rLol")` in Pycharm and I'm getting the output Lol and not Loll.And online IDE is giving the output Hell
Lol

There's too much confusion regarding how others are saying \r works and how it actually is working on Pycharm.
[OS : Windows 10]

Comment: The PyCharm console is not a real terminal, it has quirks like this.

Comment: The same with the online IDE. Run the program in a terminal window.

Comment: Hello @Akshu, as Barmar said, it,s not a real terminal at all.

Comment: In Spyder it produces the output you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a so called **Carriage Return \r** in your String, so the substring "Lol" after this symbol **\r** will move to the next line.

After executing your program:

```
print("Hell\rLol")
```

the result on your console will be:

```
Hell
Lol
```

If you're interested in learning more about escape characters, then take a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp